# How can i force a username and password to be entered when browsing a Jenkins service?

Tags: jenkins

To browse to Jenkins UI, I can  bring up a web browser and go to URL http://:
This seems to be a bit insecure, is there a way I can force username and password to be passed in the url , something like

```
        http://<myServer>:<port>?uname=<username>&pwd=<pwd>
```

So if the user ever tried

```
        http://<myServer>:<port>
```

It would give an error that uname and pwd are required or it would just fail to browse ?
This would then verify against Jenkins user credential

Is this possible within Jenkins on Windows Server ?

Comment: You need to setup global security so only the authorized users are allowed to view your Jenkins UI. This has to be done from an admin user id and you can uncheck the Allow anonymous read access.

Comment: So basically if i setup global security and disable anonymous read access , the if someone tries to browse to http://<myServer>:<port> then they will be prompted for user name and password ? so if the user has logged in and they log out and re-browse will they automatically be taken to the Jenkins UI or will they need to login again regardless ?

Comment: But if i use Active Directory and not the Jenkins DB then it will require the use to login with their AD user name and pwd ?

Comment: if you disable anonymous read access and someone tries to browse they will be prompted for user name and password.
Yes If they log out and re browse they will be taken to login page again. 
Yes if you use Active Directory then it will require the user to login with thier user name and pwd.

Comment: just to clarify , if they are logged in and re-browse , they will be taken to the UI and dont need to re-log back in , right ?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: So it really setting Project-based Matric Authorization Strategy ? Cause i dont see the option "Allow anonymous read access" once i have set this ?

Comment: That would be if you want more finer control, It is actually a good practice to do. IF you trust all your logged in users you can leave it at "Logged in Users can do anything"

Comment: Also , can i add MFA for Jenkins , so if the user tries to browse then they will be presented with a QR Code first and if that is successful , then they will be prompted with the login ?

Comment: Well i cant see the see the option "Allow anonymous read access" option , so i assume it has been disabled because i dont have "Logged in Users can do anything"  set .

Comment: If you want MFA setup an SSO. As part of SSO you can implement MFA.

Comment: ah you mean using the SAML Single Sign On(SSO) plugin for Jenkins, if so i will look at that, but does that give a QRCode ?